# Splitting multi value cells in Excel into rows

Tags: vba, excel, split

I encountered a problem in excel, I'm planning to split a multi-valued cell into rows through VBA.

This is my current table

[image]

Then I'm trying to make it like this

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you ever tried to do it yourself?

Comment: The impression I get from this place is that the idea is that you make a stab first and post your code and we will help you. Writing people's code from scratch is not generally the done thing. Have you tried searching - I have seen this sort of question come up quite often?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.  I'm assuming your 'Emails' column is column B and you start on row 1.

```
Option Explicit

Const ANALYSIS_ROW As String = "B"
Const DATA_START_ROW As Long = 1

Sub ReplicateData()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iSplit() As String
    Dim iIndex As Long
    Dim iSize As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End With

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ANALYSIS_ROW).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    For iRow = LastRow To DATA_START_ROW Step -1
        iSplit = Split(ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Value2, ",")
        iSize = UBound(iSplit) - LBound(iSplit) + 1
        If iSize = 1 Then GoTo Continue

        ws.Rows(iRow).Copy
        ws.Rows(iRow).Resize(iSize - 1).Insert
        For iIndex = LBound(iSplit) To UBound(iSplit)
            ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Offset(iIndex).Value2 = iSplit(iIndex)
        Next iIndex
Continue:
    Next iRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```